# Rails User Groups - Set Group Owner In Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have user created groups in my application. I'm confused as to how to set the user that creates the group as an owner. I want there to be able to be multiple owners so it's a 'has-many-through' relationship. I can create/edit/delete a group.

So my question is how do I insert the current user_id and the group_id into the group_owners table at the time that the group is created?

Here is what I have that works so far:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :group_owners
  has_many :user_groups, through: :group_owners

end
```

**Group Model**

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :goup_owners
   has_many :users, through: :groups_owners

   validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
   validates :visibility, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}

   VISIBILITY_TYPES = ["Public", "Private"]

end
```

**Group Owner Model**

```
class GroupOwner < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :user_group

end
```

**User Groups Controller - Create Action**

```
def create
   @usergroup = UserGroup.new(usergroup_params)
   if @usergroup.save
     redirect_to user_groups_path
   else
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

I assume something needs to go in the user group create method but I'm not sure what.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I, at the time the user group is created, as add the current users id and the group id into the group owners table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes to the user group controller create method fixed my issue.

```
def create
    @user_group = current_user.user_groups.build(usergroup_params)
    if @user_group.save
      @user_group.users << current_user
      redirect_to user_groups_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create UserGroup like

```
def create
 @usergroup = current_user.user_groups.build(usergroup_params)
 if @usergroup.save
   redirect_to user_groups_path
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

This way the user group will be created with current users id and the group id into the group owners table.

Comment: Thanks, that does not seem to create the record in the group_owners table however. No errors, but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In you UserGroup model, set a boolean for owner.

```
create_table |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :group
  t.boolean :owner
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :owner

  scope :groups, ->(*g) {where(group_id: g.flatten.compact.uniq)}
  scope :users, ->(*u) { where(user_id: u.flatten.compact.uniq)}
  scope :owners, ->{where owner:true}
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: user
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups

  def owned_groups
    groups.merge(UserGroup.owners)
  end
end
```